# Must there be a type assertion in non-initial reducers?

Tags: cyclejs

Since the type of of a reducer [is defined as](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/blob/243cd2534ff2728ad8c84b1ce9d85fe13e61fd8b/state/src/types.ts#L2)

```
export type Reducer<T> = (state: T | undefined) => T | undefined;
```

In my reducers that are not the initial reducer, I must declare

```
state = state as State
```

Am I missing something, or is this considered a minor inconvenience, please?

Answer (score 0):

Non-initial reducers can be typed (in TypeScript) as `(state: T) => T` and these will be compatible with the `Reducer<T>` type found in the library. Here is an example from my codebase, the first snippet is an initial reducer that needs to treat the case for undefined:

```js
const initReducer$ = xs.of(function initReducer(prev?: State): State {
  if (prev) {
    return prev;
  } else {
    return {
      selfFeedId: '',
      currentTab: 0,
    };
  }
});
```

This second snippet is a non-initial reducer where I am sure the previous state is not undefined:

```js
const setSelfFeedId$ = ssbSource.selfFeedId$.map(
  selfFeedId =>
    function setSelfFeedId(prev: State): State {
      return {...prev, selfFeedId};
    },
);
```

Notice that when these streams are merged, the resulting type can be `Stream<Reducer<State>>` with no casting involved:

```js
const reducer$: Stream<Reducer<State>> = xs.merge(initReducer$, setSelfFeedId$);
```